# JavaScript HtML get values from one input

Tags: javascript, html

I can't find any info about it in the internet.
I wrote in one text box two values separated by a space  .For example

44 55. How to transform these input ​​into two variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an input with id `myInput`, then:

```
document.getElementById("myInput").onclick=function(){
   var firstVar = this.value.split(" ")[0];
   var secondVar = this.value.split(" ")[1];
}
```